# Is it ever explained why Maya is rejected by the Ocean Agency?

Tags: daphne-the-brilliant-blue

In the anime: "Daphne in the Brilliant Blue," is it ever explained why Maya is rejected by the Ocean Agency?

I never found out, but in the 1st episode (I may have missed something) Maya seemed like the best possible candidate. So why the rejection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is explained and the reason is understandable. Ensure you have finished the series:

> She was rescued by the Ocean Agency once she surfaced in a life pod, approximately 100 years after the Elpida catastrophe. She was resurrected, and unsuccessfully treated by the Ocean Agency psychologists. Her memories were altered with that of a different life, which was done to enable her to function and live her life. Her brother, whom was the only other survivor, surfaced ~60 years earlier and posed as her grandfather, and was not allowed to tell her the truth due to the involved risks and agreements he made to ensure her safety. She was rejected because she was a survivor of the city of Elpida, and the entire catastrophe was covered up, therefore making her a risk to the agency and government.